# ImportError: cannot import name 'cache' from 'functools'

Tags: python, functools

All the solutions I managed to find are only on `lru_cache`. But in my case `dir(functools)` shows that that very `lru_cache` does reside in `functools` while `cache` does not! How can I solve this?

Comment: `cache` is Python 3.9 pretty sure

Comment: @JoshuaNixon missed the spot, I googled the error itself

Comment: Are you trying ``from functools import cache'' at GoogleColab ? If yes, maybe it is better to use ``from functools import lru_cache'', then call @lru_cache(maxsize=None) . This worked for me (with GoogleColab - that is currently using Python 3.7).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The [documentation for `functools.cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache) states that it's only available from Python 3.9 onwards. If you're using an earlier version then the documentation also states that it's the same as using `lru_cache(maxsize=None)`, so that's probably your best option.

Comment: The source on `cache` was not that brand new so that I could've thought it is a new feature of `functools`. Didn't think 3.9 is so old by now.

Comment: @Kaiyakha Python 3.9 is the latest released branch. `cache` *is* a new feature of `functools` as of Python 3.9, as I said. If you are using an earlier version it will not be available and you must use `lru_cache` instead.

Comment: I only said this to ease the hatred on my post

Answer (score -3):

```py
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=128)
def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)


def main():
    for i in range(1000):
        print(i, fib(i))

    print('Done')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: As per my existing answer the documentation states that `cache` is equivalent to `lru_cache` with a `maxsize` of None, not 128. Additionally, please do not post code-only answers - explain what the code is showing in terms of answering the question. Printing the Fibonacci Sequence was not part of the question.